# Variable's value is different that the assigned one

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am using a fragment which shows differnet informations about an object. Inside onCreate of the fragment I retrieve some values from the object and store them in global variables:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        String serializedShow = getArguments().getString(SHOW_TO_LOAD);
        mShow = (new Gson()).fromJson(serializedShow, Show.class);
        mScope = mShow.getScope();
        mLanguage = MainActivity.getSystemLanguage();
        mLanguage = mLanguage.replace("_", "-");
        mId = Integer.valueOf(mShow.getShowId()).toString(); //this line is important
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "DetailFragment onStart, Id is " + mId);
    }
```

As you can see I assign to this variable a specific ID. I use the log to check if the value of mId is the correct one and it is. Everything works well so far.
Next int he code the user can click a button to upen up am url in the browser. The URls are different with each time this fragment is created (every time this fragment shows different stuff)

```
private void fetchIMDBId(){
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "starting IMDBAsyncTask with id " + mId);
    new Async4().execute(mId);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_launch:
            fetchIMDBId();
            return true;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

As you can see the method fetchIMDBId() gets called. I have a log line to check if the value of mId which was set before in onCreate is the same.
**It is not the same**, its a totally different value.
Specifically is the id of the object that was being displayed in a previous instance if this fragment.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

E: variable declaration

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String LOG_TAG = DetailFragment.class.getSimpleName();
...
private String mScope, mLanguage, mId;
...

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
}
```

E: full source [here](https://github.com/fermatijoe/shows2/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/dcs/shows/DetailFragment.java)

Comment: Is mId class variable or instance variable?

Comment: What do you mean? I added the declaration to the main post

Comment: Are there any setters on mId? Are you sure the two logs you are checking are for the same instance of your class?

Comment: The passed object is valid. The mId returned by the log in oncreate is the right one, aand apart form there the mId varable is not touched anymore. I added the full source for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are not assigning your mId correctly to the Async task. You should apply the mid to the async task method so that the corresponding mId from each fragment is called

```
private void fetchIMDBId(String mId){
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "starting IMDBAsyncTask with id " + mId);
    new Async4().execute(mId);
}
```

and then call the method within the fragment

```
fetchIMDBId(this.mId);
```

Comment: Still does not work. The onStart Log displays the correct value but the log in  fetchIMDBId displays another value.

Comment: Have you tried to to set the mId variable to static?

Comment: IT WORKS I owe you my life Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you :) happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Try using `this.mId` and also check if your fragment object is same as previous one.

Call `this.fetchIMDBId()` instead.